# Regex Extract All using pig

Tags: regex, hadoop, apache-pig

This is my sample data (attributes) to match with:

```
[87027^适用年龄#619081^12-36个月,108389^国产/进口#619192^国产,108376^包装单位#619113^盒装,12210^分类#121491^牛奶粉,108385^奶源产地#619164^澳洲/新西兰,115919^配方#651827^常规配方奶粉,12212^段位#121499^3段,108380^净含量#619152^2kg以上]
[108385^奶源产地#619183^其它　,12212^段位#121499^3段,87027^适用年龄#619081^12-36个月,108376^包装单位#619120^桶装,108389^国产/进口#619196^进口,12210^分类#121491^牛奶粉,115919^配方#651827^常规配方奶粉,12241^价格#121803^200-299元,108380^净含量#619147^800-1000g]
[87027^适用年龄#619081^12-36个月,108389^国产/进口#619192^国产,108376^包装单位#619113^盒装,12210^分类#121491^牛奶粉,108385^奶源产地#619164^澳洲/新西兰,115919^配方#651827^常规配方奶粉,12212^段位#121499^3段,108380^净含量#619152^2kg以上]
```

So I'm trying to match with all the values in between the numbers. So for the first data line, I would want to match with the value between 87027 and 619081, and the value between 619081 and 108389 and so on for every value.

Here is my code so far:

```
data = LOAD 'SHORT.txt' USING PigStorage() AS (number:chararray, user:chararray, item:chararray, attributes:chararray);
B = FOREACH data GENERATE REGEX_EXTRACT_ALL (attributes, '\\^(.*?)[#|,|\\]]'); 

DUMP B;
```

Please let me know if you there is any other information needed. Thanks!

Comment: Curious. Did my answer help?

Comment: I understand the regex you provided & it works in the link you provided, but I'm still unable to get the code to work.

Comment: my output just shows up as:
()
()
()

Answer (score 0):

This pattern captures what you describe:

```
\d+?(\^.+?[,#\]])
```

Example here: https://regex101.com/r/pOPWwY/2

Looks like Hadoop needs double-escaping of backslashes, so bear that in mind when testing the above.

If want to exclude the markers `, # ]`, then:

```
\d+?(\^.+?)[,#\]]
```